# Migrating Service Account between BigQuery projects

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have 5 BigQuery projects namely Project1, Project2… Project5.

I have a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-server) created in Project1. I am using this same service account in all the 5 projects for programatic insertion of rows.

Now I plan to delete  Project1 for some reasons. My question is whether the service account that exits in Project1 also get deleted?
Since the other 4 projects use this service account, will the insertion to these projects fail?

If the service account gets deleted, is there a way to migrate this service account to any of the other project.

I don't want to create a new pair since the projects are in production and requires roll outs to handle the newly generated keys. Any suggestions in this regard.

Comment: Right, the service accounts belong to a project so that service account will disappear. Why do you need to remove the project? Even if you delete all the billable resources you will be able to use the service account.

Comment: @adrián We need to delete the project because it has corrupted data and we no longer need it. So if I understood correctly the service account gets deleted along with the project. So will the other projects which make use of this service account to make api calls continue to work ?

Comment: If you delete the Project1, you'll delete the service account as well. Then, the other projects will work but the API calls made with that service account will fail. If you have corrupted data I recommend you to remove the billable resources in Project1 and leave it there just to keep the service account.

Comment: @Adrián thanks for the reply. Anyways we created a new service account in one of the other project since it's not a very tedious task. Wanted to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @John, can you pls post your solution as an answer and accept it so it is clear that the issue is solved (though not in the way you would prefer)?  Q's which are actually solved but don't appear to be (no accepted answer) confuse stackexchange users and searchers a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service accounts gets deleted when the project that contains it is deleted, so i am not sharing it across projects.

So I created separate service accounts per big-query project for my use case.